# How to remove a certain character?

Tags: c#, json

I'm developing a program, I know how to de-serialize a JSON. But I don't know how to de-serialize it when it's just one string in quotes.

When I request the JSON, and put it into a string, then write it to the console.
I get this:
[image: http://a.pomf.se/tlfnnz.png]

How do I remove those quotes so it's just a normal string?

The [API Documentation](https://github.com/hummingbird-me/hummingbird/wiki/API-v1-Methods#user--authenticate) has this:

> Response
>
> Returns 201 Created if succeeds, 401 Unauthorized otherwise.
>
> Returns user's authentication token as a JSON string (i.e. in double quotes). This token must be used as the auth_token parameter for methods that require authentication.

For the auth_token to work I need to remove the double quotes from that string.
Now, this may not have anything to do with JSon as I see now.

How do I remove those double quotes?

Comment: that's not json, it looks like it's base 64 encoded.

Comment: that is valid json. `echo json_encode('foo')` will produce `"foo"`. Either those quotes were in the original JSON, producing `"\"ey....kY\""`, or you didn't output the decoded text.

Comment: it might be a value within a json object, yes, but it's not "valid json" any more than "look at my horse my horse is amazing"

Comment: @MarcB is a mere string valid JSON? I thought `{ key: value }` was the minimum. Edit: nevermind, see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/), and [RFC 4627](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627).

Comment: @CodeCaster, `{}` is the minimum

Comment: It's indeed base64-encoded json, although the snippet [does not really make sense](http://pastebin.com/xV5Gdd25).

Comment: @CodeCaster: json is a general representing of any "data" on the right-hand side of a JS assignment operation. `var js = "foo"`;, the `"foo"` is the valid json.

Comment: @Stepepper, the question doesn't even address the underline issue your having.. if I had to guess, I would say you aren't setting the content-types in your request and response objects properly.. where are you getting this string value, and how do you know it's json in the first place?

Comment: I'll edit the question, wait up.

Comment: @MarcB, I don't agree with that.. json is Javascript Object Notation.. not a value assignment.. `{}` is an object. but is `""`?

Comment: I edited it and changed the question, maybe that should be something easier?

Comment: Is [`str = str.Trim('"')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what you want?

Comment: @MarcB, it was a rhetorical question, because the answer is no.. it's not an object. `""` is a string - a value type; a primitive.. try this `JSON.parse("""")` .. then try `JSON.parse("{}")`

Comment: obviously the first one is a syntax error "Missing ) after argument list"

Comment: I haven't seen that syntax error before.. usually it is 'Unexpected end of input' or 'Unexpected string'.. still.. try it as `var MyVar = ""; JSON.parse(MyVar);` .. it raises the same issue.. the point being, you aren't going to parse a primitive into a object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: hmm.. nevermind, an escaped string does seem to work.. so I suppose you're correct.. a primitive type is valid json after all..

Comment: @brett: problem is you're doing this inside javascript. `myvar = "";` is setting myvar equal to an empty string. in essence, the `""` **IS** the json, and the JS parser is decoding that json into a string again. what's in myvar is no longer json, it's the native representation of an empty string. that's why a lot of early json parsers were essentially `var foo = eval(json_string_here)`. the json string was essentially executed.if you wanted to decode the json representation of that `""` empty string, it'd have to be `JSON.parse('""')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I remove those double quotes?

You don't want to. You want to parse it. You do that like you do with any JSON, using NewtonSoft.Json:

```
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"foo\"");
```

Yields the string `foo`.

Comment: Instead, I just put in 'var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(auth_token);' , right?

Comment: I don't know where you stored the response body of the request, but if that is in a string named `auth_token` you're good to go.